# Android adding files on install

Tags: android

Is there any way to add files in Android storage on install? Like some image/video that will be stored there on install and if needed it would be loaded, like pushing a button or something like that ?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to add files in Android storage on install?

Not really. You are welcome to package files as assets, then copy them to internal storage on first run of your app. Or, depending on what sort of file it is and what you want to do with it, you might be able to just use the original copy of the file as an asset directly.